# Tracking Azure DevOps build activities

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have set up multiple Azure DevOps build pipelines that are triggered by submitting pull requests to a GitHub repo. Whenever a build happens, I can navigate to that build's page and see its build steps and whether the build was successful. How do I pull that information out programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull information out of Azure DevOps programmatically, I can use the [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api). This SDK provides multiple clients to pull various data from Azure DevOps. As @Levi Lu-MSFT's answer hinted, the data I wanted can be obtained from the build client.

I installed the SDK in a conda environment with this YAML:

```
name: DevOpsData
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip==19.2.3
  - nb_conda_kernels==2.2.1
  - papermill==1.0.1
  - pandas==0.23.4
  - scikit-learn==0.20.0
  - lightgbm==2.2.1
  - pip:
    - prompt_toolkit==2.0.9
    - azure-cli==2.0.69
    - azure-devops
```

I pulled what I needed using this script:

```
# Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
    personal_access_token = "MY_ACDESS_TOKEN"
    organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/MY_ORGANIZATION"

    # Create a connection to the org
    credentials = BasicAuthentication("", personal_access_token)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

    # Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
    build_client = connection.clients.get_build_client()

    # Get the first page of builds
    project = "MY_PROJECT_NAME"
    get_builds_response = build_client.get_builds(project=project)
    index = 0
    while get_builds_response is not None:
        for build in get_builds_response.value:
            duration = build.finish_time - build.start_time
            seconds = duration.days*(24*60*60)+duration.seconds
            print("[{}]\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{:,} seconds".format(
                index, build.build_number, build.source_branch, build.result,
                seconds
            ))
            index += 1
        if (get_builds_response.continuation_token is not None
            and get_builds_response.continuation_token != ""):
            # Get the next page of builds
            get_builds_response = build_client.get_builds(
                continuation_token=get_builds_response.continuation_token)
        else:
            # All builds have been retrieved
            get_builds_response = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific build status by [restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1
```

But I guess you probably want a build status badge to be added to your git repo.

First go to the **Pipelines** page in your Azure Devops, select the pipeline of your git repo.
On the right top corner, click on the **eclipse** and choose **status badge**
[image]

**Copy the sample markdown link.**

[image]

Then go to your github repo, and paste the status markdown link in the **read.me** file and commit the change to your repo. The build status will be shown as below in your github repo
[image]

And aslo you need go to the **Project Settings** of your azure devops. Go to the **Settings** under **Pipelines**. Make sure **Allow anonymous access to badges** checkbox under General

[image]

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer. In fact, I want to get the data itself to track changes in build history. However, your initial answer provided me with the hint I needed: look to the build part of the restful API.